# Why git rm --cached not remove local ever tracked file but others

Tags: git, caching, gitignore, git-rm

When untrack a file in the git repository, use `git rm -r --cached .`. This will not remove the ever tracked file in local storage, but when other developers fetch this commit with `git pull`, the ever tracked file will been removed on their machine storage.

You can reproduce it with:

1. save current work. (**Machine A**)

```
git add .
git stash save "work position"
```

2. create a new file and commit it.(**Machine A**)

```
echo hello>>file_not_to_track
git add .
git commit -m "add file file_not_to_track"
```

3. pull from another machine(or another directory)(**Machine B**)

```
git pull
```

show files now

```
ls
file_not_to_track  README.md
```

4. untrack the file.(**Machine A**)

```
echo file_not_to_track >> .gitignore
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "untrack file_not_to_track"
git push
```

show files now

```
ls
file_not_to_track  README.md
```

5. fetch code(**Machine B**)

```
git pull
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From example.com:my/example_project
   6525df1..f413f8b  master     -> origin/master
Updating 6525df1..f413f8b
Fast-forward
 .gitignore        | 1 +
 file_not_to_track | 1 -
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 delete mode 100644 file_not_to_track
```

show files now

```
ls
README.md
```

As it shows `git rm -r --cached .` remove ever tracked file on others repo but not in current repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Machine A:**

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Above command will remove files from the index (*both README.md and file_not_to_track*). At this time, **the index is empty**. However, file_not_to_track is still exists on file system.

> **--cached**: Use this option to **unstage and remove paths only from the index**. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

```
git add .
```

With **add** action, git just added only **README** file. (file_not_to_track has been ignored).

**On Machine B:**

> 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

With **pull** action, git recognizes that **file_not_to_track** is gone. Git perform an delete action.

Answer (score 2):

`git rm --cached` tracks a change of removing the file from git, but does not remove the local copy. Running `ls` locally will still show the local file, but if you pull from another machine, the change of removing that file will be applied, and the file removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how option **--cached** works, it removes the file from the git index. Working tree files will be left alone. However, Git will no more track this file in your local repository.

Look here for the --cached option:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm